# How do I see the request body with node-soap

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I have some sample code that looks like the following:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url  = "http://www.example.com?wsdl";

var soapHeader = "<AuthHeader>...</AuthHeader>";

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
  client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader);

  var args = {
       'arg1': 1
    }
  };

  client.SomeMethod(args, function(err, result){
   if(err){

    throw err;

   }
   console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
});
```

The problem is the request is failing due to either an incorrect header or arguments I'm passing. It would be much easier to debug if I could see the entirety of the request body. How is that done?

Comment: tcpdump, wireshark, fiddler, hand-made proxy

Comment: @AlexBlex There should be a way built into the client to see the request body, but I can't find it.

Comment: There is [client.lastRequest](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#clientlastrequest---the-property-that-contains-last-full-soap-request-for-client-logging), or you can listen on events like `request` to get the payload before it is sent. I believe non-intrusive sniffer is a bit simpler and reliable for your needs though.

Comment: more, client has lastResponse and both Headers for lastResponse and lastRequest

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is still relevant to you, but here goes:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url  = "http://www.example.com?wsdl";

var soapHeader = "<AuthHeader>...</AuthHeader>";

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
  client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader);

  var args = {
       'arg1': 1
    }
  };

  client.SomeMethod(args, function(err, result){
   if(err){

    throw err;

   }
   console.log('last request: ', client.lastRequest);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
});
```

The extra console.log statement with "lastRequest" will show the XML request that is being sent, which can be used for debugging. Hope this helps.